# Best way to learn Signal Integrity

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, signal-integrity

I am currently working on ECAD. Just to add more technical values to my work, I want to learn Signal Integrity and Thermal Analysis. What are the books,links you would suggest me to learn it?

I am equipped with both Cadence SPB 16.5 and PADS 9.3. I suppose SI can be done with the tool Allegro PCB SI GXL and XL. Is it the tool SI experts use commonly or will you suggest me something else?

Couple of years from now, what would be the advancements in ECAD and how should I be prepared for it?

Really looking for some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never heard of the field of "signal integration", but there is an area known as "signal integrity" that is often abbreviated as "SI". If you are looking to learn about signal integrity it will be much easier to get there from a background in engineering or physics than from a background in CAD.

Answer (score 6):

Start with the two books by Lee Ritchey (Right the First Time vol I and II). Then read Eric Bogatin's book. The reason I like those books are that they are so hand-on and free of unsupported "theories".

In my SI courses I often use SigXplorer from Cadence as "the" tool and you can do a whole lot of SI analysis with that tool alone. That and Hyperlynx are probably the two most used tools.

Predicting the future is always difficult, but by now it's clear that pre-route SI analysis is a key skill and rule based layout is a key skill now and in the future.

PS: You can easily find [Lee Ritchey's first book as a pdf on-line for free](http://www.thehighspeeddesignbook.com/) or very cheap (fully legal).

Comment: I'd recommend starting with Bogatin's book as Lee's book is a little terse and can be daunting if you don't have a good understanding of the fundamentals, which Bogatin's book will give you.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I had a few good links, but SE won't let me post them, so this is the single best:
 [my book lists](http://www.amazon.com/gp/richpub/listmania/byauthor/A3ET91G60ATKU2/ref=cm_pdp_lm_all).

I'd recommend the books by Brooks, or Bogatin, as a start.

Gary

Answer (score 3):

**Signal and Power Integrity - Simplified (2nd Edition)** [Hardcover]

Eric Bogatin (Author)

ISBN-10: 0132349795

ISBN-13: 978-0132349796

Publication Date: July 27, 2009

[http://www.amazon.com/Signal-Power-Integrity-Simplified-2nd/dp/0132349795/ref=pd_sim_b_2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132349795)

I'm 30% through this book and it is excellent so far. Everything is explained extremely well. It really gives you a visceral understanding of the topic. It is a great intro to the field. It is easy and interesting to read, although, if you already know a particular topic the long thorough treatments can be tedious. However, you can just skip over those sections.

Answer (score 2):

Get the current editions by Eric Bogatin and Henry Ott.  Opinions may differ, but IMHO, there's simply nothing else to say on the subject.